# Using this(), not understanding why I need to have an object defined for it to work

Tags: javascript, jquery

In the below code, I use jquery to find an element that I clicked, "this", and whatever I clicked, I want "this" background to change to red.  However, it only works if I define a tag inside the change color line or the "what did I click" line.

Why won't the code below change the color of whatever I clicked to red?

```
<script>


$(document).ready(function() {

   $(this).click(function() {

      $(this).css("background-color","red");
   });

});

</script>
```

Comment: Welcome to [so]. What specifically do you want to change? The body? Another element?

Comment: i want to change whatever i click, so if i click on the p or h1 tags it changes them to red.

Comment: To avoid polluting the document namespace, you cannot bind certain events directly to it. This is, to avoid huge amounts of performance loss in your scripting, and for other reasons (such as modifying objects that you do not own).

Comment: `this` refers to the element the handler is bound to, not the element that triggered the event (they can of course be the same. Inside the `ready` handler, `this` refers to `document`.

Comment: if you want everything to change to red, change the line `$(this).click(function() {` to `$('*').click(function() {`. This won't be particularly useful on its own, as soon your entire page will be red as people click on stuff.

Comment: Use `$('*').` to attach your click handler to all elements.But it is not good practice .

Comment: i do not want to change everything when i click, i simply want to click the "h1" or "p" tags if they are clicked. i wanted to do it without if statements and using "this"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want only the `<h1>` and `<p>` elements without directly using an `if` statement, use the appropriate selector, which will set it on every element.

```
$('h1, p').click(function () {
    $(this).css('background-color', '#F00');
});
```

If you need to, wrap the code in a `$(function(){})` call, which is a shorthand for `$(document).ready(function(){})`.

However, to not create so many event listeners, you can instead use a single event listener that binds to the document and deal with that by filtering the result:

```
$(document).click(function () {
    $(event.target).filter('h1, p').css('background-color', '#F00');
});
```

As Felix noted, it would be more jQuery-like to do this, though this achieves pretty much the same thing:

```
$(document).on('click', 'h1, p', function () {
    $(this).css('background-color', '#F00');
});
```

Comment: Why not use jQuery's event delegation support instead of `filter`ing the elements? (I mean, it doesn't really matter, but that would be more jQuery-ish I guess).

Answer (score 1):

`this` refers to the element the handler is bound to, not the element that triggered the event (they can of course be the same).

Inside the `ready` handler, `this` refers to `document`. So you are binding the click event handler to `document` and hence `this` inside the event handler will always refer to `document` as well.

It looks like you are looking for [`event.target`](http://api.jquery.com/event.target/):

```
$(document).click(function(event) { // `document` is clearer than `this`
   $(event.target).css("background-color","red");
});
```

`event.target` always refers to the element that triggered the event.

I recommend to read [the jQuery tutorial about basic event handling](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-basics/).

Comment: This is much nicer than my aggressive solution which is binding to every element.  Nice work, @felixkling

Answer (score 1):

if you want `h1` and `p` tags to change to red when clicked, change the line

```
$(this).click(function() {
```

to

```
$('h1, p').click(function() {
```

The `this` keyword inside your `click` event handler refers to the actual element being processed, ie the `h1` or `p` element. You could use `event.currentTarget`, but there's no real reason why you should.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function() {

 $('*').click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation()
    $(this).css("background-color","red");

 });

});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/uVAhs/